# About Difference Between ' and " in the Title

Tags: prepositions, difference, conjunctions, writing

I have a YouTube channel and i don't want to any mistake on grammar or syntax.

Which one is true? I saw a lot of news channel and all of them using different types. Is all of them can be used?

For instance; (They're titles so X comments on Y is included)

```
'This is a great moment' - X comments on Y

'This is a great moment!' - X comments on Y

"This is a great moment" - X comments on Y

"This is a great moment!" - X comments on Y
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a stylistic choice only.

In general usage, British practice is to use single quotation marks to set off a quote and American practice is to use double quotation marks.

All normal rules of grammar and style go out the window when writing newspaper headlines, and to a lesser extent when writing titles in general—look up the term "headlinese" for more information.